# No such file or directory found on amazon ec2 server python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, background-service, file-not-found

This code is running in background service and working perfectly on localhost and uploaded the backup file successfully on Amazon S3 server but when this code deployed on ec2 amazon server its give this error.

**Error on Server:**
Error while creating DB backup - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'db_backups/automate_uat_new_27092018_07.backup.sql' at 2018-09-27 07:50:00.100217

**Code:**

```
    try:
    os.putenv('PGPASSWORD', PASS)

    filename = 'automate_uat_new_{0}.backup.sql'.format(datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y_%H"))
    zip_filename = filename + '.gz'
    ZIP_BACKUP_PATH ='db_backups/{0}.gz'.format(filename)
    FILE_BACKUP_PATH = 'db_backups/{0}'.format(filename)

    ps = subprocess.Popen(
        ['pg_dump', '-h', DB_HOST, '-U', DB_USER, '-d', DB_NAME, '-f', FILE_BACKUP_PATH],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    output = ps.communicate()[0]

    import gzip
    import shutil

    with open(FILE_BACKUP_PATH, 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open(ZIP_BACKUP_PATH, 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
        print('DB backup sql file has been completed at {0}'.format(datetime.utcnow()))


    ZIP_BACKUP_PATH = 'db_backups/{0}.gz'.format(filename)
    if (os.path.exists(ZIP_BACKUP_PATH)):
        upload_to_s3(ZIP_BACKUP_PATH, zip_filename)
    else:
        print('DB backup sql file not found to upload on s3 at {0}'.format(datetime.utcnow()))

except Exception as ex:
    print('Error while creating DB backup - {0} at {1}'.format(ex, datetime.utcnow()))
```

Comment: Is your server Windows or Linux? What OS is your localhost as well?

Comment: This website host on Linux based server.

Comment: OS is ubuntu 16.04 Lts